# php json_encode display with number not correct from array

Tags: php, json

This is my array

`$data['myarray'] = ["1" => 1.2, "10" => 0.911, "50" => 0.811, "100" => 0.37];`

if using json_encode it will display like `json_encode($data['myarray']`

`{"1":{"1":1.2,"10":0.91100000000000003,"50":0.81100000000000005,"100":0.37}}`

I don't understand why my var has change to other number

Comment: what is your php version?

Comment: @Curious_Mind PHP 7.1.25

Comment: This the Output for 7.1.25 - 7.3.0     `{"1":1.2,"10":0.911,"50":0.811,"100":0.37}`, Demo : https://3v4l.org/Es4IP#output

Comment: Yes, I have tested in https://ideone.com/bIqFDR working normal. I have upgrade to 7.26 but same issue. I don't known what's error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this config

`ini_set('serialize_precision', 14); 
ini_set('precision', 14);`
This is issue from php 7.1